# Transform a tensor into another

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of arrays

```
T = [np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]), np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]), np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1,
 0]]), np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]), np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])]
```

then a tensor if

```
T = np.array(T)
```

The shape of that tensor is then `(5, 4, 3)`. I would be interested to reshape that tensor to get `(4, 5, 3)`. In other words, 4 matrices of dimension (5, 3). The first matrix would be simply

```
 [[1, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0]
  [1, 0, 0]]
```

The second

```
 [[1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1]
  [1, 0, 0]]
```

and so on

I tried to just transpose the tensor, but that did not help me.

How can I reshape `T` to get a dimension `(4, 5, 3)`?

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, kindly mark it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following

```
np.transpose(T, (1, 0, 2))
```

The second parameter refers to the position of axes of the tensor. Since `T` has a shape of `(5, 4, 3)`, which means axis `0` is `5`, axis `1` is `4`, and axis `2` is `3`.

So, to make the tensor have a shape of `(4, 5, 3)`, just arrange them using `np.transpose`.

Alternative way of doing it

```
T.transpose(1, 0, 2)
```

More explanation from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

> axes : list of ints, optional
>
> By default, reverse the dimensions, otherwise permute the axes according to the values given.

Answer (score 1):

Hand made solution, uglier but..

Given the input array:
    import numpy as np

```
T = [np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]),
     np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]),
     np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]),
     np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]),
     np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])]

T = np.array(T)
```

To get the "first column" as it appears in the code:

```
print(T[:,0])

# [[1 0 0]
#  [1 0 0]
#  [0 0 1]
#  [0 1 0]
#  [1 0 0]]
```

So, you could use a list comprehension to get the required result:

```
np.array( [ T[:,n] for n in range(len(T[0])) ] )
```